# Regex para validar um campo alfanumérico de 5 dígitos

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou fazendo uma expressão regular pra validar um campo alfanumérico de até cinco dígitos. O primeiro campo deve ser apenas numérico, os demais podem ser letras ou números:

```
ex: 1A, 11A, 111A, 1111A, 1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111
```

Restrições:

- Não pode haver uma letra entre dois números: `ex = 1A11, 2A2, 222A1`;
- Não pode começar com uma letra: `ex = A11`;
- Não pode haver letra seguida de letra: `ex = AA, AA1, A1A`;

O que fiz primeiro: `\d?\w?\w?\w\w`

Ele só aceita a partir do segundo caractere seja ele letra ou número. O que não deveria acontecer, pois o primeiro deve ser exclusivamente número. E aceita letras entre números.

Depois cheguei a isso: `^(\d{0,5})([A-Z]{0,5})$`

Aqui o único problema é que ele aceita que se comece com letra e ponha letra seguida de letra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\d{0,5}` significa "de zero a 5 dígitos". Mas pelo que entendi, você quer que tenha pelo menos um dígito no início, então *poderia* mudar para `\d{1,5}` (entre 1 e 5 dígitos).

Mas se analisarmos as regras, veremos que uma letra não pode estar no começo nem no meio, e não pode ter duas letras seguidas, então ela só pode estar no final (e só pode ter no máximo uma). Então na verdade você precisa que a string tenha o seguinte:

- tenha entre 1 e 4 dígitos
- seguido (opcionalmente) de um dígito ou uma letra

Então você poderia usar `^\d{1,4}[A-Z\d]?$`.

Os [delimitadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` são respectivamente o início e fim da string. Assim eu garanto que a string só tem o que está na regex.

Depois temos `\d{1,4}` (entre 1 e 4 dígitos). Em seguida, `[A-Z\d]?` significa "uma letra de `A` a `Z` ou um dígito", e o `?` [torna este trecho opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/06XbNq/1/) esta regex funcionando).

Testando:

```js
let r = /^\d{1,4}[A-Z\d]?$/;

let strings = ["1A", "11A", "111A", "1111A", "1", "11", "111", "1111", "11111", "1A11", "2A2", "222A1", "A11", "AA", "AA1", "A1A"];

// r.test retorna "true" se a string está de acordo com a regex
strings.forEach(s => console.log(s, '=', r.test(s)));
```

---

Um detalhe é que `[A-Z\d]` só aceita letras maiúsculas. Se quiser considerar também minúsculas, basta trocar para `[A-Za-z\d]`.

E usar `\w` não é uma boa opção, pois [este atalho](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes), além de considerar letras e números, também considera o caractere `_`.